# submit checkbox with textbox value using php

Tags: checkbox, textbox

Sorry to take your time. First of all please do not rebuke me for asking this question.

I have a set of checkboxes and each has a textbox. Here, I have two questions:

1) I want to display the textbox only after clicking the checkbox.

2) how I want to send the value of the checkbox that was clicked along with the textbox value and then display it in the form of the checkbox and textbox back. for your info, textbox is used by the user to fill out a little note on the checkbox that was clicked.

I have google and have managed to send the value of checkbox using arrays ... but the problem is, I do not know how to send the textbox showing the textbox. will they still be able to use an array or how?

below is a picture of my screen

```
[CB1] No abnormality and significant [... tb1 ..............]<br>
[CB2] Dominant mass                  [... tb2 ..............]<br>
[cb3] Calcification                  [... tb3 ..............]<br>
[CB4] Asymmetrical density           [... tb4 ..............]<br>
[CB5] Other                          [... tb5 ..............]<br>
```

I include the code below which I have used:

```
<?php
   $finding_arr = array('No significant abnormality','Dominant mass','Calcification','Asymmetrical density','Other');
    $finding = unserialize($row['finding']);

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($finding_arr); $i++){
     $checked = in_array($finding_arr[$i],$finding)? " checked" : "";
        echo "<input type='checkbox' id='finding' name='finding[]' value='$finding_arr[$i]'$checked> $finding_arr[$i] <input name='finding[]' type='text' id='f_note' value='$f_note[]' size='70'><br>\n";
        }
        ?>
```

I desperately need your help. thx in advanced...

Answer (score 0):

(1) To edit the page before submitting anything to the server you will want to use javascript or jQuery (for example, jQuery's .hide() and [.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/))

(2) Without a little more information I'm a little confused what it is you want to do. Also, providing relevant code would make it easier to see what's going wrong.

Comment: I think there's a bug in SO -- maz posted a fair bit of code but it is  not being displayed.  I could see the code when I was trying to edit the post, but now I can no longer edit it.  I've flagged it for SO folks to have a look.

Comment: thx for your quick reply... my problem is i don't know how the best way to store the textbox value along the value of checkbox into database.. is array can do that?.. how array can store both value in one field and than display it again in checkbox and textbox back... sorry if my explanation a bit confusing

Comment: Again, it's hard to help without a little more detailed explanation of what you'd like to do. For example, there are many different databases you could use and your implementation would depend on that. In general though, you will want to put all your textboxes and checkboxes inside <form></form> tags and then provide a submit button. Then you can use PHP to access your GET or POST variables through the $_GET and $_POST global PHP variables.